# Ignore JScript exceptions in VS2010 script debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2010, exception, extjs, jscript

is there a way how to ignore VS2010 Java Script exception dialog which is shown when attached to JSCript running in IE.
We have ExtJS project and teher's some exceptions occuring in ExtJS we know about, but clicking 10 times Ignore is very annoying.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the following methods:

- try/catch around the known exceptions
- [window.onerror](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/better-error-handling-with-window-onerror/) for uncaught exceptions